# Can I tell if argument labels are optional from Xcode auto-complete?

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete

I understand how some argument labels for Swift methods can be optional. For example, this method of the UIToolbar class:

```
func setItems(_ items: [UIBarButtonItem]?, animated: Bool)
```

What's bothering me is that Xcode auto-complete adds the `items` label, but then shows an error telling me to remove it:

[image]

I could remove it at the point I'm accepting the auto-completion, but auto-complete doesn't give an indication of which labels are optional -- it doesn't show the underscore:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing here that would avoid the need to always go back and delete the unwanted labels that auto-complete adds? Or does this seem like a bug that I should report to Apple?

Comment: When you press "TAB" after selecting the function from the autocompletion list then the entire `items: [UIBarButtonItem]?` part should be selected, so that entering "newItems" replaces it *without* the argument label, and everything is fine.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, but you're right!